# How to empty select2 previous data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have 2 select2 component in my project. Values of one of them is depended on value of other one which is selected. Here is the code:

```
  $('#states').on('change', function() {
     $.get({
            url: 'https://mydomain/cities.php/?sid='+$(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                citiesData = new Array();
                $.each(response, function(index, el) {
                   citiesData.push({'id' : el.id, 'text' : el.title});
                });

                $('#cities').select2({data:citiesData});
            }

        });
  });
```

Problem is select2 which shows cities doesn't get empty for each change of states and cities of selected state is added to pre-selected state.

How can I empty select2 of cities before inserting new data?

Comment: why are you using `select2` as a function? Maybe, that's an element with ID `select2` in html?

Comment: select2  is an extension for Yii.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your ajax success function.

```
$('#cities').select2().val();
```

And to empty the select2

```
$("#cities").empty();
```

Comment: `...empty();` not `empty;`

Comment: Wow ... the second solution works! I love you both, beginner and Max :* You are my today's heros!

Answer (score 0):

just empties the list or dropdown in which you are loading data

Comment: I think you should try to empties the array cities data